# how to permute from a bag?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a relation called stuff whose schema is like this:

```
grunt> describe stuff;
stuff: {child_id: long,parent_id: long}
```

I would like to group child_ids by parent_id and then generate an output as a list of ordered pairs between different child_ids. For example, if there are child_id of 1,2,4 and 5 under a parent_id of 100, my desired output is like this:

```
1,2
1,4
1,5
2,1
2,4
2,5
4,1
4,2
4,5
5,1
5,2
5,4
```

Do I have to write an eval function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need CROSS operator. Here is an example:

**INPUT**

```
1,2
1,1
1,3
1,4
2,5
2,3
2,6
```

**CODE**

```
inpt = load 'parent_child.csv' using PigStorage(',') as (parent_id: long, child_id: long);
tmp = foreach inpt generate parent_id, child_id as b1, child_id as b2; -- needed to use CROSS in the nested FOREACH
parentGroup = group tmp by parent_id;

perms = foreach parentGroup { 
    bro_1 = tmp.b1;
    bro_2 = tmp.b2;
    brothers = cross bro_1, bro_2;
    brothers = filter brothers by b1 != b2; -- remove relationship to itself
    generate group as parent_id, brothers;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

schema - perms: {parent_id: long,brothers: {(bro_1::b2: long,bro_2::b2: long)}}

```
(1,{(1,2),(3,2),(4,2),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(2,3),(1,3),(4,3),(2,4),(1,4),(3,4)})
(2,{(3,5),(6,5),(5,3),(6,3),(5,6),(3,6)})
```